# OSSEC Slack Integration

Tags: slack-api

I want all OSSEC notifications to be routed to a Slack room instead of email. 2.9.Beta5 has a ossec-slack.sh active response script. The relevant parts of my ossec.conf are:

```
<command>
  <name>ossec-slack</name>
  <executable>ossec-slack.sh</executable>
  <expect>srcip</expect>
  <timeout_allowed>no</timeout_allowed>
</command>


<active-response>
  <command>ossec-slack</command>
  <location>local</location>
  <level>1</level>
</active-response>
```

This works for SSH logins (failed and successful), but as far as I can tell doesn't trigger anything else. What am I doing wrong/how are others doing this? Is this just beta software being beta software?

Answer (score 10):

First make sure your `ossec-slack.sh` file has the correct information in the top:

```sh
# FILE: /var/ossec/active-response/bin/ossec-slack.sh

SLACKUSER="ossec"
CHANNEL="#slack_chanel"  # include the hash "#"
SITE="https://hooks.slack.com/services/TOKEN"
SOURCE="ossec2slack"
```

Your `"SLACKUSER"` is the same as the "Customize Name" field that you set in your Slack WebHook Integrations page.

[image: SLACKUSER Integration Example]

Now that your `ossec-slack.sh` file is set up you can test your Slack integration manually:

```
/var/ossec/active-response/bin/ossec-slack.sh
```

Running the script manually will post recent entries from your alerts log file:

```
/var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.log
```

When this script is triggered as an active-response, it will only post the information for the current alert, rather than posting from your log file.

When you have verified that you can post Slack messages manually, add the following XML blocks to your `ossec.conf` file:

```xml
<!-- FILE: /var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf -->

<ossec_config>
    <command>
        <name>ossec-slack</name>
        <executable>ossec-slack.sh</executable>
        <expect></expect> <!-- no expect args required -->
        <timeout_allowed>no</timeout_allowed>
    </command>

    <active-response>
        <command>ossec-slack</command>
        <location>local</location>
        <level>3</level>
    </active-response>
</ossec_config>
```

The settings above will post to your Slack channel whenever a level 3 or above alert is triggered.

**Note:** no arguments are required within the `<expect>` tag. But the `<expect>` tag itself, is required. See OSSEC's [active-response documentation](http://ossec.github.io/docs/syntax/head_ossec_config.active-response.html#element-expect) for more information.

To test this integration, restart your ossec server:

```
/var/ossec/bin/ossec-control restart
```

You should see the `"OSSEC Started"` alert very quickly:

[image: OSSEC Message posted to Slack]

If you do not see the alert, check your logs for any misconfigurations:

```
tail /var/ossec/etc/logs/ossec.log
tail /var/ossec/logs/active-responses.log
```

Comment: Something to be aware of is that if you're running this in a more standard environment with a master and multiple agents, you need to change the location in active-response to server or the active-response command will be executed on the agent that raises the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but adding on here. To ensure this works, make sure you don't have this set in `/var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf`. If it's there, just remove.

```
<active-response>
  <disabled>yes</disabled>
</active-response>
```

Comment: for me, the active response alert_id's didn't match any log entry in alerts.log or alerts.json